# Reducing multiple windows with mvvm

Tags: wpf

I have a main window which have a few buttons, each button represent different object (of the same kind) which require different graph values.What is the best way to use one view and window in order to present all the different objects on the same graph, (one at time of course) depends on what button we choose.

This is the view(deleted XAML code that seems to me unnecessary for the question):

```
<layout:SampleLayoutWindow x:Class="AreaChart.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
xmlns:chart="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Charts;assembly=Syncfusion.SfChart.WPF"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PL" 
xmlns:layout="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.Windows.SampleLayout;assembly=Syncfusion.Chart.Wpf.SampleLayout"
UserOptionsVisibility="Collapsed"                   
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Height="643.287" Width="1250.5"        
Title="2017">
<Grid>

<Grid.Resources>
  ...........................................
    <chart:AreaSeries x:Name="AreaSeries" EnableAnimation="True"
                      **XBindingPath="date" 
                      Label="Favourite"
                      YBindingPath="rate" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding CurrenciesHis}"** 
                      ShowTooltip="True" >
    <chart:AreaSeries.AdornmentsInfo>
    <chart:ChartAdornmentInfo AdornmentsPosition="Bottom"  
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                      ShowLabel="True">
    <chart:ChartAdornmentInfo.LabelTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
  ....................................
<ComboBox
ItemsSource="{Binding YearsList}"
SelectedItem="{Binding Year}"
/>
```

This is the ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
public ViewModel()
{
    Year = DateTime.Now.Year - 1;
    UpdateCurrencies();
}

protected void UpdateCurrencies()
{
    //  Indexs that holds actuall api retrived values
    int i, j;
    //  cR- current rate in string format, urlContents - the whole Api retrived data
    string cR, urlContents;
    //  For api syntx, add 0 or not, depends on the current date syntax
    string c;

    CurrenciesHis = new ObservableCollection<Model>();//Model objects collection

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    for (int l = 1; l < 13; l++)
    {
        if (l < 10)
            c = "0";
        else
            c = "";

        //  Use the public property Year, not the field _year
        var url = "http://data.fixer.io/api/" + Year + "-" + c + l + "-01?access_key=&base=USD&symbols=EUR&format=1";
        urlContents = client.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
        i = urlContents.IndexOf("EUR");//Finds the desired value from api recived data
        j = urlContents.IndexOf("}");

        cR = urlContents.Substring(i + 5, (j - 2) - (i + 5));

        CurrenciesHis.Add(new Model() { rate = Convert.ToDouble(cR), date = "01/" + l.ToString() });
    }

    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrenciesHis));
}


private int _year;
public int Year
{
    get { return _year; }
    set
    {
        if (_year != value)
        {
            _year = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Year));
            UpdateCurrencies();
        }
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<Model> CurrenciesHis { get; private set; }


public System.Collections.IEnumerable YearsList 
        => Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year - 30, 30).ToList().AsReadOnly();
```

}

And this is the main window which we chose which currency we want to be represented on the graph that on the view by clicking a button that opens the window that contain the graph:

```
<Window x:Class="PL.WindowMenu"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PL"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="WindowMenu" Height="643.287" Width="1250.5" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

<StackPanel Margin="0,0,2,2" RenderTransformOrigin="0.511,0.536">
    <StackPanel.Background>
        <ImageBrush/>
    </StackPanel.Background>
    <Grid Height="612" x:Name="NewGrid">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="92" Margin="346,221,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="290"  Click="Button_Click"></Button>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="92" Margin="346,221,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="290"  Click="Button_Click2" Command="{Binding Path=ButtonClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"></Button>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="92" Margin="346,221,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="290" Click="Button_Click3"></Button>
     </Grid>
 </stackpanel>
 </window>
```

ViewModel of the Main Window:

```
 class RTViewModel : ObservableCollection<RTModel>
{
    IBL bl;

    public ICommand ButtonClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new EuroClickCommand();
        }
    }

    public void OpenGraph()
    {

        AreaChart.MainWindow myWindow = new AreaChart.MainWindow();
        myWindow.Show();
        //Window.GetWindow(this).Hide();
    }

    public RTViewModel()
    {
     }
```

EuroClickCommand:

```
  class EuroClickCommand : ICommand
{


  public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        var viewModel = (RTViewModel)parameter;

        viewModel.OpenGraph();
    } 

}
```

What is the best approach to preform this task ?

Comment: If you are using button click events, you are not using MVVM.  You should be have the buttons `Command` property in XAML bound to an `ICommand` property on the view-model.

Comment: In our last episode, we did a viewmodel that updates chart series data when a property changes. I suggest you take Bradley's suggestion with an ICommand property, and use the CommandParameter property on each button to pass a different parameter to the command from each button. You could give your UpdateData function a parameter, and have the command's execute method cast the CommandParameter value to the appropriate type before calling UpdateData(x).

Comment: Are these three completely different types of data? That's a slightly more complicated problem, but still not very difficult in WPF.

Comment: It's the same object with just different properties values so it represent a different currency

Comment: As long as your viewmodel raises the right notifications when properties change, you can update whatever you like and it should be reflected in the UI. Look into the command thing. A `RelayCommand<T>` or `DelegateCommand<T>` class will be handy for that -- use MVVMLight or just steal somebody's code off the internet (talent borrows, genius steals, programmers copy and paste). I'm going to be unavailable from this evening until mid-May, but lots of people here can help you if you run into any snags. Good luck with the project.

Comment: Thank you for all the help !.I edited the question and added command for one button for the meantime .I didn't understand though how would I send the parameter from the command (I called it EuroClickCommand) to the UpdateCurrencies function located in the ViewModel of the graph window

Comment: Any update about your goals and my answer ? did it help ?

Answer (score 0):

**You got several alternatives to achieve this**. One is to have several graphs in your view, and have one of them with `Visibility = Visibility.Visible` and the others `Visibility.Collapsed`. It's good in the case your graphs are differents.

But another solution, less heavy in resources is to **simply change the binded ObervableCollection**. I propose this following MVVM implementation to change your graph with the buttons.

In your View:

```
<chart:AreaSeries ItemsSource="{Binding CurrenciesHis}"/>

<Button Command="{Binding ChooseGraphCommand}" CommandParameter="1"/>
<Button Command="{Binding ChooseGraphCommand}" CommandParameter="2"/>
<Button Command="{Binding ChooseGraphCommand}" CommandParameter="3"/>
```

and in your ViewModel:

```
private ValuesType _currenciesHis;
public ValuesType CurrenciesHis
{
    get => _currenciesHis;
    set
        {
            if (value == _currenciesHis) return;
            _currenciesHis = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
}

private ICommand _chooseGraphCommand;
public ICommand ChooseGraphCommand => _chooseGraphCommand ??
    (_chooseGraphCommand= new DelegateCommand(
        s =>
        {
            switch(s)
            {
                default:
                case 1:
                    CurrenciesHis = graph1; // graph1 contains your data
                case 2:
                    CurrenciesHis = graph2;
                case 3:
                    CurrenciesHis = graph3;
            }
            // or
            CurrenciesHis = allGraphs[s-1]; // array or List of your data
        },
        s => true));

// implementation of INPC
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

[YourNameSpace.Annotations.NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

And this helper class:

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null) {}

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);
    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged() => CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

And yet, in your annotations:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class NotifyPropertyChangedInvocatorAttribute : Attribute
{
    public NotifyPropertyChangedInvocatorAttribute() { }
    public NotifyPropertyChangedInvocatorAttribute([NotNull] string parameterName)
    {
      ParameterName = parameterName;
    }

    [CanBeNull] public string ParameterName { get; private set; }
}
```